# how can create custom menu side in bootstrap or foundation?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation, sidebar

hi there how can create a custom sidebar menu in bootstrap or foundation
exact like this site:

http://zurb.com/word

I found one in here via boostrap.

[enter link description here](http://seegatesite.com/bootstrap/simple_sidebar_menu.html)

it's like first one but it open over page. I want body be resize (not hidden or overflow)

another example is w3schools.com menu side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bootstrap one IS resizing the page when you click the button at the top.  It only covers the page when you hover.  To get exactly what ZURB.com is doing, you can use the bootstrap template that you linked, and add some jquery like this:  (I got this jquery by modifying the sidebar js file form the bootstrap page that you linked.)

```
     $("#sidebar-wrapper").hover(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled-2");
        $('#menu ul').hide();
    });
```

Comment: thanks u. can u please tell how can I close it in default?